# Laravel 5.5 setting pivot extra fields value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I'm new to laravel, my problem is i'm trying to set values to extra fields in the pivot table

post_tag

```
Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->uuid('uuid')->unique();
    $table->uuid('app_uuid');
    $table->uuid('tag_uuid');
    $table->uuid('post_uuid');
    $table->timestampTz('created_at');
    $table->timestampTz('updated_at')->nullable();
});
```

i want to be ab to set `uuid` as php function

```
uuid();
```

and `app_uuid` to

```
$request->app_uuid
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways of adding extra field is to pass data as key-value to attach() method where key is id of a relation field  and value is the extra field in pivot table

```
 $post->tags()->attach([$request['id'] => ['uuid ' => uuid()]]);
```